# How to invalidate cache for object graph with Redis?

Tags: java, spring, caching, architecture, redis

I'm going plan for using Redis as cache in my REST service. But I don't find any efficient way to invalidate cache item in Redis for object graph - I mean the relationship of an object.

**Example:**

```
class A {
   Integer id;
   String title;
   String name;
   List<B> bEntities;
...
} 

class B {
   Integer id;
   String name;
...
}
```

How can I invalidate A when B has changed with Redis cache? Is there an abstract way to handle this case properly ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to implement some routine to invalidate it. Redis doesn't support something like this. The request for `A` could be `lazy loading`. You could have the reference of `A` on `B` and remove `A` from Redis when `B` changes. Then the `lazy loading` for `A` should automatically works for you.

Comment: @FelipeOriani thanks for your answer. My solution is that I use redis hash field to cache A object,  store field - value for simple type and for dependent field like bEntities - I store A:B = [BId1, Bid2]. And I also store another redis hash for B1 with Bid1 and B2 with Bid2.